# Combine output vectors into dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, vector

I wrote a function with a vector of length `3` as output which has a structure like this:

```
func <- function(input){
    a <- 15+input
    b <- 5+input
    c <- -5+input
    return(c(a,b,c)) 
}
```

and I have input values `input <- seq(200,300)`

I'd like to call the function `100` times (`length(input)`), then I'd like to calculate the output vectors for each value in `input` and I'd like to combine the output vectors into a dataframe.

How can I do this efficiently?

**EDIT**: I made a mistake. `length(input)` is `101` in that case.

Comment: Does using ```return(data.frame(a,b,c))``` instead of ```return(c(a,b,c))``` work?

Comment: It does, but, in the end, I'd like to have only one dataframe. You suggest that I would combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply`, which gives you a 3x101 matrix, transpose it, then convert it to a data frame. If you want the colnames to be a, b, c then you can set them after:

```r
sapply(input, func) |> # Apply `func` to every input separately
  t() |> # Transpose
  as.data.frame() # convert to data frame
```

This gives output:

```
     V1  V2  V3
1   215 205 195
2   216 206 196
3   217 207 197
4   218 208 198
5   219 209 199
6   220 210 200
7   221 211 201
8   222 212 202
9   223 213 203
10  224 214 204
...
...
...
```

Alternatively, if you name your return list with a, b, and c, you can get the names out:

```
func <- function(input){
  a <- 15+input
  b <- 5+input
  c <- -5+input
  return( c(a = a,b = b, c = c) ) # Note the names 
}

sapply(input, func) |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame()
```

returns

```
      a   b   c
1   215 205 195
2   216 206 196
3   217 207 197
4   218 208 198
5   219 209 199
6   220 210 200
7   221 211 201
8   222 212 202
9   223 213 203
10  224 214 204
...
...
...
```

Finally, you can return a data frame from your function, do an lapply to apply the function to each `input` then bind all the rows together:

```
func <- function(input){
  a <- 15+input
  b <- 5+input
  c <- -5+input
  return(data.frame(a = a, b = b, c = c)) 
}

lapply(input, func) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
```

which returns the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer`

```
func <- function(input) {
    as.data.frame(outer(input, c(15, 5, -5), `+`))
}
```

such that

```
> func(seq(1, 100))
     V1  V2 V3
1    16   6 -4
2    17   7 -3
3    18   8 -2
4    19   9 -1
5    20  10  0
6    21  11  1
7    22  12  2
8    23  13  3
9    24  14  4
10   25  15  5
11   26  16  6
12   27  17  7
13   28  18  8
14   29  19  9
15   30  20 10
16   31  21 11
17   32  22 12
18   33  23 13
19   34  24 14
20   35  25 15
21   36  26 16
22   37  27 17
23   38  28 18
24   39  29 19
25   40  30 20
26   41  31 21
27   42  32 22
28   43  33 23
29   44  34 24
30   45  35 25
31   46  36 26
32   47  37 27
33   48  38 28
34   49  39 29
35   50  40 30
36   51  41 31
37   52  42 32
38   53  43 33
39   54  44 34
40   55  45 35
41   56  46 36
42   57  47 37
43   58  48 38
44   59  49 39
45   60  50 40
46   61  51 41
47   62  52 42
48   63  53 43
49   64  54 44
50   65  55 45
51   66  56 46
52   67  57 47
53   68  58 48
54   69  59 49
55   70  60 50
56   71  61 51
57   72  62 52
58   73  63 53
59   74  64 54
60   75  65 55
61   76  66 56
62   77  67 57
63   78  68 58
64   79  69 59
65   80  70 60
66   81  71 61
67   82  72 62
68   83  73 63
69   84  74 64
70   85  75 65
71   86  76 66
72   87  77 67
73   88  78 68
74   89  79 69
75   90  80 70
76   91  81 71
77   92  82 72
78   93  83 73
79   94  84 74
80   95  85 75
81   96  86 76
82   97  87 77
83   98  88 78
84   99  89 79
85  100  90 80
86  101  91 81
87  102  92 82
88  103  93 83
89  104  94 84
90  105  95 85
91  106  96 86
92  107  97 87
93  108  98 88
94  109  99 89
95  110 100 90
96  111 101 91
97  112 102 92
98  113 103 93
99  114 104 94
100 115 105 95
```